# How does tcp-segmentation-offload work on linux?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

Before routing, the kernel doesn't know which interface will be chosen, it can't know if it supports TSO or not. So I am amazing how tcp-segmentation-offload works.

Comment: Without knowing the interface, kernel doesn't (yet) know the maximum size of packets, etc. Just routing (and protocol) is part of networking, and it is done before handling most of the work.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Do you mean that the full tcp packets with ip header is not constructed yet when routing happens?